# How can I make my container transparent without making the whole site transparent too?

Tags: css, background, transparency, rgba

How do I make the white container background transparent like it is [here](http://www.webmarketingsolutionsessex.com/jobsite/)

Background picture shows through without it being affecting by the opacity code for the container?

The container seems to be the `content-size:#fff;` in the css

Comment: use 2 pictures as in the example you've posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, you want to modify the background to be transparent without making all the children transparent. E.G. You don't want to do `opacity: 0;`

Instead use the transparent background-color.

```
.content-size {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: just to add to this, you can do background-color: rgba(127,127,127,0.2) for a semi-transparent.

Comment: That's What I wanted!! Thanks

Comment: Thanks Josiah.  I though opacity would have worked.  I know now. thanks again

Comment: @user3420851 please if any of the answers is the one that solved your question please clic on the *Accept answer* icon as a way of grattitude

Answer (score 1):

using RGBA

```
<style>
.content-size { 
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5); 
}
</style>
```